# Neovim unable to detect Django packages: Getting 'Unable to import 'django.*' error

Tags: python, django, neovim

I've recently configured Neovim for my development workflow, but I'm encountering an issue with Django packages not being detected properly. Whenever I try to import any Django package or use Django functions within Neovim, I receive an error message like this:

```bash
Unable to import 'django.conf'
```

I've ensured that Django is properly installed and working outside of Neovim, but within Neovim, it seems to have trouble locating the Django packages. I've checked my Neovim configuration and paths, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Neovim and Django packages? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem to get Neovim to properly detect Django packages?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _I've checked my Neovim configuration and paths_ Show those to us.

Comment: @JohnGordon
https://github.com/josean-dev/dev-environment-files/tree/main/.config/nvim
I have taken all the configurations from here.

Comment: Are you in your  `venv` when you enter `nvim` and do you have `django-stubs` installed?

Comment: Also after checking the config I see that you are using `pylint` as your linter. So `pylint-django` package from PyPi can help as well.

Comment: what _:python -m pip freeze_ produces?

Answer (score 0):

The precise answer requires further information on your neovim LSP config and python development environment.
Which python LSP server do you use? Do you use a virtual environment?

If you are using a virtual environment, your LSP may not detect the packages installed in that environment.
Your LSP must have a way to specify such configuration. For example, if you are using `pyright`, you can specify above details in 'pyrightconfig.json` file. Here is an example config:

```json
{  
  "venv": "<venv-name>",  
  "venvPath": "<venv-path>/",
  "stubPath": "<project>/src" // path to local packages or modules
}
```

Check `pyright` documentation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).
You might find following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847159/how-to-set-python-interpreter-in-neovim-for-python-language-server-depending-on) helpful.